# Worklight, stop the migration script

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to stop the worklight plugin from firing the migration script?

Most of our team has 6.1.0.01-20140418-0637 
but one other member of our team has 6.1.0.01-20140515-1501.

When he downloads the app from svn, it seems the upgrade/migration script runs and removes all customization in the (shell)native directories and sets them back to default.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a parameter to tell worklight not to fire the migration script?
2. Should the migration script be running on minor version changes?
3. Why does the upgrade script wipe out all customizations/plugins in the (shell)native directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes
3. Unknown - if you are an IBM customer or business partner, please [open a Problem Management Record (PMR)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) so the development team could look into it (provide a link to this question and a demo project if possible as well).

Comment: Ok ill create a pmr. Thanks